# Does the caster know when an Invisibility spell ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, invisibility, concentration

If a spell caster puts invisibility on someone else, and that person leaves the caster's immediate area, and somehow becomes visible--by attacking, presumably--does the caster know that the spell if over (so that they could cast another spell requiring concentration)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Please check the linked question to make sure it covers yours; if not, please clarify what part of your question's not already addressed by the linked one.